# How to get and insert ID CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I save my data like this

```
public function saveInvestors($id = 0)
{
    $data = array ('id' => $id );
    $data2 = array ('ref_id' => $data['id]);

    if ($id == 0) 
    {
       return [$this->db->insert('investor', $data), $this->db->insert('leveling', $data2)];
    }
}
```

my `id` on `$data` is auto increment on database while `id` on `$data2` is not my problem here is that I couldn't get the `id` on `$data` and insert it on leveling but it always returning 0

Comment: Not sure if typo during copy/paste but the following line is wrong: `$data2 = array ('ref_id' => $data['id]);`    `id` should be in quotes. `$data2 = array ('ref_id' => $data['id']);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the inserted id after inserting it into the database:

```
$this->db->insert('investor', $data);
$new_id = $this->db->insert_id();
```

As seen in the documentation: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/helpers.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    public function saveInvestors($id = 0)
{
    $data = array('id' => $id);
    if ($id == 0) {
        $this->db->trans_begin();
        $this->db->insert('investor', $data);
        $id_investor = $this->db->insert_id();

        $data2 = array('ref_id' => $id_investor);
        $this->db->insert('leveling', $data2);

        if ($this->db->trans_status() === TRUE) {
            $this->db->trans_commit();
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            $this->db->trans_rollback();
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
}
```